# Is the image mapping of the inverse relation the same as the original relation's preimage mapping?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose R is a relation from X to Y, and S is the inverse relation to R. Is the image mapping of S, the same as the preimage mapping of R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if by image mapping you mean the appropriate map from $P(X)$ to $P(Y)$ and by pre-image mapping you mean the appropriate map from $P(Y)$ to $P(X)$. Note that some people use $R^{-1}(y)$ to mean $\{ x : x \in X \land f(x) = y \}$, but this notation is **not** the pre-image mapping referred to above. Instead if we want image and pre-image mappings to be inverses then we need to have $S(A) = R^{-1}(A) = \{ x : x \in X \land f(x) \in A \}$.